Availability with "for" or "in"
Could you please tell me if the following sentences are correct?

We are currently offering availability for late June onwards.

We only have availability in late June onwards.


Thanks in advance.

We only have availability from late June onwards.

Could you rephrase it as "We don't have any availability until late June"? That would be much simpler.

They mean different things. we are currently offering suggests it could change, with other dates becoming available.

There are many common ways of writing this, I think both are acceptable.

@user66974 Using both "from" and "onwards" seems redundant. It's not bad, but doesn't seem necessary.

Generally, both for and in require complements that are noun phrases. But onwards is an adverb, here modifying are offering or have, or perhaps some implied verb like  extending. So late June onwards isn’t a noun phrase, and thus can’t serve as the complement for either preposition (for or in).
